# Loading pretrained model with Python tensorflow v.0.9.0 in Java tensorflow v.1.2.0

Tags: java, python, tensorflow

When both Java and Python tensorflow versions are 1.2.0, it seems we can use SavedModelBundle (Java) and Saved Model API (Python) in order to save a trained model in Python tensorflow and load the model in Java tensorflow (Not with Maven).

However, I could not find a way to properly load a model in Java when the version of Python is below 1.0.

I trained a model and saved it as .pb, .sd, and .txt files in Python tensorflow (0.9.0) and followed the [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java) instruction in the tensorflow website to load the model. However, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting 
to use uninitialized value policy/mean_network/hidden_1/b
            [[Node: _retval_policy/mean_network/hidden_1/b_0_0 = 
_Retval[T=DT_FLOAT, index=0, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
(policy/mean_network/hidden_1/b)]]
            at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
            at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
            at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:285)
            at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:235)
            at Carpole.executeGraph(Carpole.java:42)
            at Carpole.main(Carpole.java:30)
```

Does anyone know how to properly load a pretrained model in Java in the most recent version (since I cannot find previous version API anymore) without using Saved Model API?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my Python code for saving:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    …..
    saver_def = self.saver.as_saver_def()
    print(saver_def.filename_tensor_name)
    print(saver_def.restore_op_name)

    self.saver.save(sess, 'trained_model'+str(itr)+'.sd')
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '.', 'trained_model'+str(itr)+'.pb', as_text=False)
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '.', 'trained_model'+str(itr)+'.txt', as_text=True)
```

And here is my Java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String dataDirPath = args[0];
    byte[] graphDef = readAllBytesOrExit(Paths.get(dataDirPath, "trained_model10.pb"));
    List<String> labels = readAllLinesOrExit(Paths.get(dataDirPath, "trained_model10.txt"));
    float[] vector = new float[4];
    vector[0] = (float) -0.09341373;
    vector[1] = (float) -0.07540844;
    vector[2] = (float)  0.00930138;
    vector[3] = (float) -0.14317159;
    Tensor input = Tensor.create(vector);

    float[] labelProbabilities = executeGraph(graphDef, input);
    int bestLabelIdx = maxIndex(labelProbabilities);
    System.out.println(String.format("BEST MATCH: %s (%.2f%% likely)",labels.get(bestLabelIdx), labelProbabilities[bestLabelIdx] * 100f));
}

private static float[] executeGraph(byte[] graphDef, Tensor input_tensor) {
    try (Graph g = new Graph()) {
        g.importGraphDef(graphDef);
        System.out.println(g);
        try (Session s = new Session(g); Tensor result = s.runner().feed("policy/mean_network/input/input",input_tensor).fetch("policy/mean_network/hidden_1/b").run().get(0)) {
        final long[] rshape = result.shape();
        }
        int nlabels = (int) rshape[1];
        return result.copyTo(new float[1][nlabels])[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, TensorFlow versions prior to 1.0 are not guaranteed to work with TensorFlow versions >= 1.0 (as per the [TensorFlow Version Semantics](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/version_semantics) and use of semantic versioning).

That said, looking at the code snippets you provided, you're loading the computational graph in Java, but are not loading the saved variables and hence you get an exception complaining that the variables have not been initialized.

Encapsulating the graph and saved variables into a single bundle is what the SavedModel format is intended for. However, if you can't use that, and if you need the graph only for inference in Java, then you might want to consider "freezing" the graph and then loading that in Java. The frozen graph will contain all the variable values in a single file.

You could try to use the [`freeze_graph`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) libraries (from the 0.9 release branch) to save such a graph.

Working with pre-1.0 releases of TensorFlow might be a challenge. If possible, I'd strongly suggest you move your model to a TensorFlow version >= 1.0 and then can avail for the API stability guarantees.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! However, somehow my tensorflow doesn't have tensorflow/python/tools module (I'm using anaconda2). I ended up upgrading to v.1.1.0, modified my codes a little bit and used Saved Model API.